# Написать post запрос на php

Tags: php, json, post, xmlhttprequest

Как правильно записать вот такой запрос на php:

> POST http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/Address/getCities HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Type: application/json Host: testapi.novaposhta.ua
>   Content-Length: 102
>
> { "modelName": "Address", "calledMethod": "getCities", "apiKey": "cc3537300145dfa379120a1143a15071" }

Comment: Получить данные в формате json нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Но все же попытаюсь ответить.

1. Для отправки запросов на сервер со стороны клиента (браузер) используются:

   - Тег FORM и вложенные теги input. Детальнее о формах: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/otpravka-dannykh-formy
   - или Библиотека jQuery в которой предоставляется технология AJAX. Детали: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
   - или язык JavaScript также предоставляющий возможность использования AJAX. Детали: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax
2. Для того что бы в браузере отобразился ответ на запрос используется:

   - серверное программирование на PHP или любом другом серверном языке;
   - или если вы хотите принять и обработать полученные данные на стороне клиента (в браузере) используйте технологию AJAX предоставляемую в библиотеке jQuery
   - или язык JavaScript. Детали: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax
3. Для конвертации java script объекта на стороне клиента в формат JSON и наоборот, используются методы:

   - JSON.parse – читает объекты из строки в формате JSON.
   - JSON.stringify – превращает объекты в строку в формате JSON, используется, когда нужно из JavaScript передать данные по сети.

Детальнее: https://learn.javascript.ru/json

4. Для конвертации JSON объекта в PHP переменную и наоборот, на стороне сервера применяются функции:

   - json_decode — Декодирует JSON строку
   - json_encode — Возвращает JSON-представление данных

Детальнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.json.php